# Converting Tiles to GeoPackage with Python

Tags: python, geopackage

I am trying to convert tiles (as PNG) into GeoPackage. In order to do so, I would like to use the [geopackage-python tool](https://github.com/GitHubRGI/geopackage-python). However, when executing the script I run into the following error:

[image]

Layer 14 is the folder with the tiles/images.

Do you have any idea on what the problem exactly is and how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to guess what the *actual* problem is because you did not give any information about the directory structure of your source files.

The error says that Python could not convert the string "Layer 14" to an integer number. It is most likely that you pointed the tool to the wrong directory, I guess it expected to be pointed at the directory in which the numerically-named zoomlevel directories reside.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your folder name that contains your TMS /XYZ  tiles does not contain a number.